# How to align text in colums in batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to get user input and align it in colums using a batch file.

What I would like to archive is put a username in the beginning of the file and let's say the age on the 20th character of the file:

[image]

But I don't know how to put an input in on a exact position inside a variable or a text file:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo.
set /p "name=Please insert your name: "
set /p "age=Please insert your age: "

set line=%name%
set %line:~21,3%=%age%
echo %line%>>%userprofile%\desktop\names.txt
goto :start
```

Comment: If you want a really nice flexible format function I invite you to try this [one](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4027)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique below pads the supplied name with twenty spaces, then echoes the first nineteen characters.

Quick example:

```bat
@Echo Off

:start
    ClS
    Echo(
    Set /P "name=Please insert your name: "
    Set /P "age=Please insert your age: "

    Set "line=%name%                    "
    >>"%userprofile%\desktop\names.txt" Echo(%line:~,19%%age%
    GoTo :start
```

Comment: Nice Solution. Could use a Restriction On the Stringlength for name though, to ensure space exists between columns one and two. After `Set /p name=`: `IF NOT "%name:~18%"=="" GOTO :start`

Comment: @T3RR0R: simply change `%line:~,19%%age%` to `%line:~,18% %age%`.

Comment: @T3RR0R, I don't see any point in providing verification or maximum character lengths on the `Set /P` input as it isn't part of the OP's question. Essentially, as the OP said "…and let's say the age on the 20th character of the file", I think I've provided enough for them to adapt the code as necessary. But I agree that to be more robust the OP should be sure that, in the case above, any input for the `name` string should verify that the name is `18` characters or less, _i.e. required character position of first age digit minus two_.

Comment: @Stephan A nicer solution still.

Comment: Thanks it works. Thoug I don't fully understand that parentesis in the code that don't close. I always thought that if you open parenteses in batch you have to close them somewhere can someone explain?

Comment: @RicardoBohner, the first character after `Echo` is ignored, most people use a space character. However when there is no string following it, as in this case, to prevent `Echo` returning its current state, e.g. `echo is on.` or `echo is off.`, a character is required following it. Most users historically used a period, `.` but it has been deemed that characters such as `(`, `/`, and `=` are more robust. I used the former, and also did so for the second instance, just in case the end user just hit the enter/return button and name and age weren't defined.